# How to change debug.keystore to custom.keystore in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I saw that the key to change debug Android for a custom key.I need to change the password and alias of your key release. I am running the following command but I can't change the password.

1. `keytool -changealias -keystore mykeystore.keystore -alias myalias
   -destalias androiddebugkey`
2. `keytool -keypasswd -keystore mykeystore.keystore -alias
   androiddebugkey`
3. `keytool -storepasswd -keystore mykeystore.keystore`

To test if the password was changed and the same alias, I repeat the process and then type the new password but it says that the password is wrong and only works with my old password. Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped me :D

Change the password

1. `keytool -storepasswd -keystore my.keystore`
2. `keytool -keypasswd  -alias <key_name> -keystore my.keystore`

Change the alias

1. `keytool -changealias -keystore my.keystore -alias my_name -destalias my_new_name`

My error was change the order to create the password -keypasswd and -storepasswd