# Facebook key hash for Android

Tags: java, android, facebook

According to [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) you need to run this command to generate key hash:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

When I do that it asks for a password. What password it needs?

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app/17732453#17732453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably it's asking for the password to the debug.keystore specified in the keytool command. which should be defaulted to `android`

If you've manually changed the password of the keystore, then you'll obviously need to enter the password that you changed it to.

Comment: Thank you. And how can I change the password if I want to?

Comment: @Narek [Does this work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901734/how-to-change-debug-keystore-to-custom-keystore-in-eclipse)

Comment: You should be able to do it with keytool, `keytool -storepasswd -keystore your.keystore`, just to clarify: this command will then ask for the existing password and allow you to change it to something else.